# adding css to a image in cake php

Tags: cakephp

I am moving my website to use cake php and before i would just have to include an image like this in my project `print("<img class='custom' alt='' src='$dish_image' />");` as you can see I included the css class to be used. But now with cake php I am not sure how to achieve as my image tag looks like this

```
 echo $this->Html->image($dishes['Dish'][0]['dish_image'], array("alt" => ""));
```

So i am not sure where to apply that custom css to it... The css is in a separate css file.

Any help would be appreciated/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image($dishes['Dish'][0]['dish_image'], array(
    "class" => "custom",
    "alt"   => ""
    )); ?>
```

Good luck!